# Button marked as span action is obscured

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, findby

Have a input box and "Choose File" button.

Image of the form and Element description :

[image]

To identify the button, following code worked:

```
WebElement UploadButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='uploader']/span[2]"));
```

However, when tried to click, it shows following error:

> Element  is not clickable at point (285,680)
>   because another element input id="fileUpload" class="form-control"
>   name="fileUpload" type="file"> obscures it

Why this button is not clickable and how can I perform Click action on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally**, when it comes to uploading files, you need to avoid the fluff around it as it's eye candy for the user, but doesn't have the real functionality.

Also, uploading a file by clicking the button is **extremely** difficult because then you'll need to use another tool to deal with the file selection pop-up (It's not handled via Selenium).

So your best solution is to instead focus on the `<input id="fileUpload" type="file">` which is how HTML handles file uploads. And leave the nice button pushing for manual acceptance testing.